# Help with getting to grips with node.js

Tags: node.js

I work full time in a PHP and JavaScript team but we are looking at a new technology to adopt. We want to dive into node.js however we all want to get the same book but we have no idea which would be the best.

Any recommendations ?

Also links would be good.

Regards

Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no real - *like in actual wood* - books out yet, Yahoo! Press has one in the [works](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/11/announcing-a-node-js-book-project/) though, title will be **"Up and Running With Node.js"**.

Right now there's a [community driven e-Book](http://visionmedia.github.com/masteringnode/) from the makers of the `express.js` framework, its source code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/visionmedia/masteringnode).

If you like videos, then should check out a couple of talks by Node's creator Ryan Dahl:

- [Introducion to Node.js - YUI Theater (May 2010)](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/20/video-dahl/)
- [GoogleTeckTalk - JavaScript on the Server (July 2010)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6k8lTrAE2g)
- [Techniques for a single stack world - JSConf.eu (Sep 2010)](http://jsconf.eu/2010/speaker/techniques_for_a_single_stack.html)

You can find even more links on our [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info).

PS: Best thing IMO is to start a little side project and use that to explore Node.js.